# Error when trying to open PNG file with Preview from command line

Tags: bash, preview

I use a bash script to generate a PNG file. At the end the script opens the PNG file, but occasionally I get the following strange error message

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the file path_to_png_file
```

The command I use in the bash script is as follows

```
(osascript -e 'quit app "Preview"' || true) && open path_to_png_file
```

I often run the script in quick succession and because of that I first quit Preview since otherwise Preview does not always load the newly generated PNG file.

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: Preview should open the file whether its running or not. Where is the file? What OS version are you running? What model Mac, and is your system volume in good order - plenty of free space, no errors in Disk Utility, etc.?

Comment: Thanks, well Preview should open the file but it doesn't consistently. In case the file is already open, Preview should rather reload the file, but this does not happen reliably, hence I close it beforehand. I doubt the issue is related to any of the parameters you mention, but I'm running macOS 10.15.6 on an Intel Mac mini. Disk utility does not mention any problems.

Comment: Error -600 indicates it's trying to send an AppleEvent to a process that doesn't exist.  You might be running into a race condition where Preview.app has not fully cleaned itself up, but osascript has returned and your next command is starting to execute.  Does it help if you put a few seconds of sleep between osascript and open?

Comment: @vykor Many thanks! As I wrote above, the issue does not occur all the time, so your explanation is likely correct. I'll implement it and report back.

Comment: @vykor You are right. Putting a bit of sleep between shutting down Preview and opening it up again did the trick. Thanks!